# Web fonts won't display in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, fonts, webfonts

No matter what I've tried, I can't get any web fonts to display in Chrome. I've created a test page and viewed it in Safari and Chrome (I'm on a Mac). Web fonts look fine on Safari, IE and Firefox--but not Chrome.

Here's the page: http://bradfordallendesign.com/test123/test.html

And here's the CSS:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'general_200thin';
    src: url('http://www.bradfordallendesign.com/fonts/General-200-Thin-webfont.eot');
    src: url('http://www.bradfordallendesign.com/fonts/General-200-Thin-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('http://www.bradfordallendesign.com/fonts/General-200-Thin-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('http://www.bradfordallendesign.com/fonts/General-200-Thin-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('http://www.bradfordallendesign.com/fonts/General-200-Thin-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('http://www.bradfordallendesign.com/fonts/General-200-Thin-webfont.svg#general_200thin') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

.test
{
    font-family:'general_200thin', Helvetica, Arial, san-serif;
    font-size: 80px;
    }
```

Any suggested fixes are much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: The Syntax is correct...you converted this typeface to webfont?

Comment: Just [base64 encode](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator) and embed [.woff` font](http://caniuse.com/#feat=woff) inside css. You have a nice article [here](http://sosweetcreative.com/2613/font-face-and-base64-data-uri).

Answer (score 2):

On my machine, all browsers give errors when loading, not just Chromium.

However, I can get the font to load if I change the URI to include the www.
http://www.bradfordallendesign.com/test123/test.html

That way, the domain is the same and you no longer get a CORS exception.

So the solution is to not specify the absolute path to the fonts; just write

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'general_200thin';
    src: url('/fonts/General-200-Thin-webfont.eot');
    src: url('/fonts/General-200-Thin-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('/fonts/General-200-Thin-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('/fonts/General-200-Thin-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('/fonts/General-200-Thin-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('/fonts/General-200-Thin-webfont.svg#general_200thin') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Then you can be sure you won't have domain name mismatches.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I got:

> Font from origin 'http://www.bradfordallendesign.com' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://bradfordallendesign.com' is therefore not allowed access.

So I am wondering whether the page has the access to the font (from bradfordallendesign.com)

I suggest that you use **the relative path** of the files instead of the absolute path. Just like [Mr Lister](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1016716/mr-lister)'s answer.

Comment: Same here, except I get this in all browsers, not just Chromium.

Comment: @MrLister Yea.. I get this in Chrome and FF.

Comment: Cool. Thanks so much everyone. I'll try the relative paths. And BTW, the font is General (http://www.fontspring.com/fonts/juraj-chrastina/general). I purchased it from Fontspring.

Comment: One more thing. How do you make web fonts show up locally in Chrome (or any browser for that matter)? I created a 'fonts' folder in the root folder where I'm building the site on my machine, but no web fonts will display locally.